# How do you exit presentation mode in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How do you exit presentation mode in WebStorm, OS X version?

[On their site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/webstorm-viewing-modes.html#d280563e226) it says "On the main menu, choose View | Exit Full Screen."  I can't get to the main menu because in presentation mode it hides that, and moving your mouse up there doesn't make it appear.

Comment: I figured out the answer so I answered my own question.  This practice is consistent with SO guidelines.

Comment: Please explain your downvote.  And if the reason is for me answering my own question, then remove it as it is inconsistent with SO guidelines. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens when Webstorm is in presentation mode and you have multiple monitors.  If it's on any monitor except the first one, then the main menu does not show up when you move your mouse to the top of the screen.

**Solution:** unplug your external monitor(s).  Then Webstorm will switch to the main monitor.  Then move your mouse to the top of the screen and the main menu will appear.

Select View > Exit Presentation Mode.

Comment: Did you know you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 9):

No need to do anything with monitors @levininja

I just had the same problem, tried escape key, minimize, etc.. and nothing worked.

All I had to do was **move mouse to the very top of the screen**, then the top menu slides down (it's in auto-hide mode) and then, **View > Exit Presentation Mode**

Comment: You say you just had the same problem. Did you have the same problem ***in the same configuration**?* Because, if you don’t have a multi-monitor system, you didn’t have the same problem.

Comment: I actually do have double monitor setup

Answer (score 1):

It has a shortcut now:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to execute the "View | Quick Switch" Scheme action.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html#tips)